# Magento2.3 generate coupon codes not generating

Tags: magento2.3, coupon-codes

In Magento2.3 I create a cart price rule and then co to manage coupon codes and click the generate button after filling out the form to generate 5 codes.
I then get a message that says

```
Message is added to queue, wait to get your coupons soon
```

Yes they are never generated.

Answer (score 2):

**To view a list of all consumers, execute the below command in terminal**

```
bin/magento queue:consumers:list
```

**The above command will give list as below :**

```
product_action_attribute.update
product_action_attribute.website.update
exportProcessor
inventory.source.items.cleanup
inventory.mass.update
inventory.reservations.cleanup
inventory.reservations.update
codegeneratorProcessor
async.operations.all
```

**After that, run command as given below**

```
bin/magento cron:run
bin/magento queue:consumers:start codegeneratorProcessor
```

Comment: Thank you @madani when I run that command I only see the below list. So what do I do if I am missing some of whats on your list?
product_action_attribute.update
product_action_attribute.website.update
exportProcessor
codegeneratorProcessor
async.operations.all

Comment: After run the this commands, 
bin/magento cron:run
bin/magento queue:consumers:start codegeneratorProcessor